# Upgrading from php5 to php7 having trouble running scripts

Tags: php

I wonder if someone can help. I gave up web programming about 3 years ago. Since returning to programming about a week ago I realize I have forgotten quite a lot and so much has changed.

I signed on to a deal with php7 but my code is php5 and when I came to running my scripts nothing really works.

For example I couldn't even connect to the database. My database connection file for php5 was

```
<?php  
$db_host = "localhost"; 
// Place the username for the MySQL database here 
$db_username = "db_username_here";  
// Place the password for the MySQL database here 
$db_pass = "db_password_here";  
// Place the name for the MySQL database here 
$db_name = "name_of_database_here"; 

// Run the actual connection here  
mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("no database");              
?>
```

I spoke to the server company and they told me everything has changed and to get my code compatible with php7. They then helped me get my database connected by giving me a sample file of how it should be which is this code.

```
 <?

/* DATEBASE CONFIGURATION */

$dbHost = "ip Address";
$dbName = "name_of_database_here";           // Database name
$dbUser = "db_username_here";           // Database user
$dbPasswd = "db_password_here";                 // Database password

function dbConnect(){
 global $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswd, $dbName;
 mysql_connect( $dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPasswd ) or error( mysql_error() );
 mysql_select_db( $dbName );
}
?>
```

I have always run my database $dbHost from localhost so I have guessed that because they haven't done the connection as localhost and done it as gobal with an ip address I have figured that the database is not on the same server as the website.

I then came to my database scripts for running from the browser to phpmyadmin and they also didnt work. Here is my database script php5.

```
<?php
require "connect_to_mysql.php";  

    $sqlCommand = "CREATE TABLE admin (
                     id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                     username varchar(24) NOT NULL,
                     password varchar(24) NOT NULL,
                     last_log_date date NOT NULL,
                     PRIMARY KEY (id),
                     UNIQUE KEY username (username)
                     ) ";
    if (mysql_query($sqlCommand)){ 
        echo "Your admin table has been created successfully!"; 
    } else { 
        echo "CRITICAL ERROR: admin table has not been created.";
    }
    ?>
```

I was wondering if someone could give me some advice on why the script isn't running
Many thanks, Gary

Comment: `mysql` extension is __removed__ in php7.

Comment: Your `mysql()` functions are no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql_connect is removed from php7.

instead of that you can use either mysqli or pdo

example with  mysqli

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
```

example with pdo

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

For more reffer details https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Sorry can you explain because the way the server company has done my connection file they have still included  mysql_connect

Comment: Is the way my connection script is set up the reason why my database scripts are not working because with the script i put up the database is connected?

Comment: @gary33 All of your code that uses `mysql_*` functions will need to be re-coded. Those functions went away in PHP7. This isn't typically your host's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help I much appreciate it. I am starting to remember everything now. It has taken me a few days for me to remember but i am getting there. Thank you everyone.